# In Google Sheets, How to specify column names?

Tags: google-sheets

I cannot modify the contents of Sheets1, 2, 3.

And there are no column names there.

And I am getting and using the values like this:

```
={
  query(Sheet1!A:C, "select * where A != ''");
  query(Sheet2!A:C, "select * where A != ''");
  query(Sheet3!A:C, "select * where A != ''")
}
```

This is exactly what I want, and it works very well.

But I tried a seemingly futile improvement:

```
=query({
  query(Sheet1!A:C);
  query(Sheet2!A:C);
  query(Sheet3!A:C)
}, "select * where A != ''")
```

This fails. I predicted that in the dynamic result you can't name the columns A, B, C.

I also tried the following but still failed:

```
=query({
  { "A", "B", "C" };
  query(Sheet1!A:C);
  query(Sheet2!A:C);
  query(Sheet3!A:C)
}, "select * where A != ''", 1)
```

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=query({Sheet1!A:C;Sheet2!A:C;Sheet3!A:C},"Where Col1 is not null")
```

Here `1st column` in this stacked array range becomes `Col1` & `2nd column` -> `Col2` & `3rd column`-> `Col3` and so on...